# How to pull up to get more data when use angular and ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

when i write a app use ionic and angular,i have a question,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls9OV.png)
this is the app screen,and i want to pull up to get more data,how can i do it?,
so,how can i write to get more data on screen by ionic+angular,i haved tried to use

```
$scope.do_infinite = function () {
    $scope.currentPage +=1;
    $http({method:'GET',url:newsListUrl+'?category=finance-news&pageno='+$scope.currentPage}).then(function successCallback(data) {
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            $scope.newsList.push(data[i]);
        }
    });
}
```

and

```
<ion-infinite-scroll on-infinite="do_infinite()"  immediate-check=”false”></ion-infinite-scroll>`
```

but it is unused

Comment: Please format the code, it's hard to read as is. There's a format tool-tip to the right when you edit.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$scope.do_infinite = function () {
    $scope.currentPage +=1;
    $http({method:'GET',url:newsListUrl+'?category=finance-news&pageno='+$scope.currentPage})
         .then(function successCallback(data) {
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            $scope.newsList.push(data[i]);
        }
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
    });
}
```

Cause reading [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionInfiniteScroll/) maybe you forgot to add this:

```
$scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
```

Hope this solve your problem